# Method that takes as argument random number of elements

Tags: java, generics

I have a method

```
public void addToList(Film film){
    listFilms.add(film);
}
```

and need to create the same method for random number of Films.
I'm trying to solve it with Collections, and generics, but Eclipse gives me an errors.
Will you please help?

Comment: Are you trying to add a list to a list? What have you tried so far? What error do you get?

Comment: Either use `List<Film>` as the parameter, or use varargs: `public void addToList(Film... film)`.

Comment: Thanks for varargs, it was exact that I have searched!

Answer (score 0):

**Varargs** will solve your problem.

Change your method signature to look like this:

```
 public void addToList(Film... films){
   ...
 }
```

And you can add 1...n films at once.

*But*: Collections will work fine as well - but you'd have to change existings calls into that method.

```
public void addToList(List<Film> films){
    ...
}
```